# How do I count the cross over in the same table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a single table `Categories`:

```
|Category|Person|
|--------|------|
|A       |P1    |
|A       |P2    |
|A       |P3    |
|B       |P1    |
|C       |P2    |
|C       |P3    |
|D       |P4    |
```

And I want to calculate how many people who have `A` also have `B` and how many people who have `A` who also have `C`. So the crossover:

```
|Category A|Category B|Count|
|----------|----------|-----|
|A         |B         |1    |
|A         |C         |2    |
|A         |D         |0    |
|B         |A         |1    |
|B         |C         |0    |
|B         |D         |0    |
|C         |A         |2    |
|C         |B         |0    |
|C         |D         |0    |
|D         |A         |0    |
|D         |B         |0    |
|D         |C         |0    |
```

But the kicker is that this needs to execute on a shitty system that requires this to run as a single query. So far I have:

```
SELECT 
    X.[Category A]
    ,COUNT(*) AS [Count]
    ,X.[Category B]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        A.Category AS [Category A]
        ,B.Category AS [Category B]
    FROM (  
        SELECT 
            Category 
            ,Person
        FROM Categories
    ) AS A
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT
            Category 
            ,Person
        FROM Categories
    ) B WHERE A.Category = B.Category
) X GROUP BY X.[Category A], X.[Category B]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

With `CTE`

```
        with CTE as
        (
        select 
        Person,Category 
        from Categories    
        )
        select distinct c2.Category , c1.Category
        ,count(case when c1.person=c2.person then 1 end ) as Count
        from CTE C1, CTE c2    
        where c1.Category <> c2.Category
        group by c1.Category,c2.Category
```

Without `CTE`

```
        select distinct c2.Category , c1.Category
        ,count(case when c1.person=c2.person then 1 end ) as Count
        from Categories C1,  Categories c2    
        where c1.Category <> c2.Category
        group by c1.Category,c2.Category
```

> Output :

[image]

Comment: @Mr.Bhosales, Unfortunately I can't use ANSI joins

Comment: @NeomerArcana use code without 'CTE' . even in your code ou also used cross join. its similar to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to build a query like this:

```
WITH CTE_CategoryCombinations AS 
( 
SELECT A.Category AS [Category A], B.Category AS [Category B]
FROM Categories AS A
INNER JOIN Categories AS B
ON A.Person = B.Person AND A.Category != B.Category )
SELECT [Category A], [Category B], COUNT(1)
FROM CTE_CategoryCombinations
GROUP BY [Category A], [Category B]
ORDER BY [Category A], [Category B];
```

This uses a CTE which is a Common Table Expression. The CTE which we create CTE_CategoryCombinations will last only for the duration of the SELECT and GROUP BY cluase after it. It will then no longer be usable and referencing it will give an error.

Advantages of using this:

1) A CTE gives the benefits of faster execution over using Sub queries as Sub queries run every time we fetch a row on which the subquery is applied. 
The CTE should be a faster approach to solving this issue and this should also give the desired result.

2) We do not use a cross join, a cross join is an expensive task. An inner join on the other hand is a more efficient way to get to the result we desire as it sets a condition on which we compare categories as we only want to compare the categories for the same sets of people.

EDIT 2:

You can use a temporary table if you do not have to stick to a single statement. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO #Categories
FROM
(
SELECT A.Category AS [Category A], B.Category AS [Category B], A.Person
FROM Categories AS A
INNER JOIN Categories AS B
ON A.Person = B.Person AND A.Category != B.Category ) AS Temp;

SELECT [Category A], [Category B], COUNT(DISTINCT Person)
FROM #Categories
GROUP BY [Category A], [Category B]
ORDER BY [Category A], [Category B];
```

Comment: Unfortunately CTE isn't available on the black box I need to run the code. But I think I can take the above and work with it.

Comment: Interesting, can you describe the tool you are working on? 
Also can you share some other constraints if there are any? 
Also, i ll provide an alternative answer which uses a temporary table. 
Though i would recommend being careful in the use of a temporary table in case your rows are huge in number, for example something like 20-30 million as efficiency does begin to drop..

Comment: I also cannot use a temp table (or I can but I'd rather stick to single query). I'm using Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script,

```
DECLARE @TABLE  TABLE   (
    Category    VARCHAR(10)
    ,Person     VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES  ('A','P1'),('A','P2'),('A','P3')
       ,('B','P1'),('C','P2'),('C','P3')
       ,('D','P4')

SELECT  T1.Category     AS  CategoryA
        ,T2.Category    AS  CategoryB
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN T1.Person=T2.Person THEN 1 END ) AS AB_Count
FROM    @TABLE  T1
INNER JOIN  @TABLE  T2  ON  T1.Category <>  T2.Category
GROUP BY T1.Category,T2.Category
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: I can't use any scripts or procedures, only SELECT statements. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: there is only a select statement here, just copy the select query and replace the table name and column name with your table and fields, that's all.